# removing a node from a generic tree

Tags: python, data-structures, tree, iteration, nodes

I am doing a self-paced challenge regarding the tree data structure for data structures and algorithm when I came across the following scaffold that I needed to fill in:

> def remove_node(self, p: 'Node[T]') -> None:
>
> """
>
> Remove the entire subtree rooted at the given node from the tree
>
> if p is the root node, set the tree's root to be equal to None
>
> make sure each node's subtree size is appropriately updated
>
> :param p: node to be removed from the tree
>
> """

I have attempted the scaffold however am not able to correctly remove an arbitrary node from the children list of another arbitrary node, say for example the root node when doing the postorder traversal of a subtree rooted at the root node. all of the other functionality I have implemented to the best of my ability and return the expected output. Here is the code snippet when I tried to remove an arbitrary node from the tree, and it returns the wrong output:

```
# allows you to execute code when the file runs as scripts not when imported as a module
if __name__ == "__main__":
    n1 = Node(1)
    n2 = Node(2)
    n3 = Node(3)
    n4 = Node(4)
    n5 = Node(5)
    n6 = Node(6)
    n7 = Node(7)

    T1 = Tree(n1)
    T1.add_node(n2, n1)
    T1.add_node(n3, n1)
    T1.add_node(n4, n2)
    T1.add_node(n5, n2)
    T1.add_node(n6, n3)
    T1.add_node(n7, n3)

    # print T1's size and root's value
    print(T1.get_size()) 
    # postorder traversal of the subtree rooted at 1
    original_ls: 'List[Node[T]]' = []
    T1.postorder(n1, original_ls)
    for i in range(len(original_ls)):
        if i < len(original_ls) - 1:
            print(original_ls[i].get_value(), end = " ")
        else: 
            print(original_ls[i].get_value(), end = "\n")

    # remove n2 from the tree
    T1.remove_node(n2)
    modified_ls: 'List[Node[T]]' = []
    T1.postorder(n1, modified_ls)
    for i in range(len(modified_ls)):
        if i < len(modified_ls) - 1:
            print(modified_ls[i].get_value(), end = " ")
        else: 
            print(modified_ls[i].get_value(), end = "\n")
```

I got the following output, which corresponds to the tree size, the post order traversal of the subtree rooted at the root node and the post order traversal of the subtree rooted at the root node after the removal of the arbitrary node `n2`, where it should've returned `6 7 3 1`.

```
7
4 5 2 6 7 3 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tree.py", line 170, in <module>
    T1.remove_node(n2)
  File "tree.py", line 103, in remove_node
    parent_children = parent._children
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_children'
```

for clarity here is the expected output

```
7
4 5 2 6 7 3 1
6 7 3 1
```

I have attempted the following - basically when the node specified in the parameter list is a root node, then set that root node equal to None and the tree's size to be equal to 0 else, you obtain both the p's parent and its  children list and remove p from its parent's list and remove p as the parent of the children. decrement the size of the subtree with the remove subtree size and update the subtree sizes of all ancestors of the removed node.

```
def remove_node(self, p: 'Node[T]') -> None:
        """
        Remove the entire subtree rooted at the given node from the tree
        If p is the root node, set the tree's root to be None
        Make sure each node's subtree size is appropriately updated
        :param p: Node to be removed from tree
        """
        if self.is_root(p):
            self._root = None
            self._size = 0
        else:
            parent = p._parent
            parent_children = parent._children

            # Remove p from parent's children list
            parent_children = [child for child in parent_children if child != p]
            parent.set_children(parent_children)

            removed_subtree_size = p.get_subtree_size()
            self._size -= removed_subtree_size

            # Update subtree sizes of all ancestors of the removed node
            current = parent
            while current is not None:
                current.set_subtree_size(current.get_subtree_size() - removed_subtree_size)
                current = current.get_parent()
```

Comment: The exception you're getting suggests that some node has `None` as its parent, but it's not the root of the list. That seems like it isn't set up properly, so I'd suggest looking for how it got in that state.

Comment: I’ve solved the issue already. there are problems with how I structure my node class, which causes the mess.